# How to Enable Custom Actions for all sub sites Document Libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, custom-actions

I am developing a Custom Menu Item Action using provider hosted app for copying documents across sites collection for  each listitem of Document Library Type. I need to enable the same custom action to all document libraries in the subsites also. what are possible values for  RegistrationType and RegistrationId to achieve my requirement . Below is my Element.xml file.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <CustomAction Id="eb90b079-9d4a-4242-981c-020fc653587d.MenuItemCustomAction1"
            RegistrationType="List"
            RegistrationId="101"
            Location="EditControlBlock"
            Sequence="10001"
            Title="SendDocument"
           >    
<UrlAction Url="https://tarunproviderhostedapp.azurewebsites.net/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}" />
```

Can Anyone suggest best  approach to meet my requirement 
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Achieved the requirement using the App Stapling.

The following articles for  reference:

[SharePoint 2013 App Deployment through "App Stapling"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2013/03/04/sharepoint-2013-app-deployment-through-app-stapling/)

[Automating add-in/app installation to SharePoint sites using CSOM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/11/20/automating-add-inapp-installation-to-sharepoint-sites-using-csom/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try custom action with content type.
example you can replace your RegistrationType="Content Type" and RegistrationId="XYZ". So all list created with the content type will be having the custom action enabled.
You can also refer [link](https://zoraradosavlevici.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/add-list-item-menu-custom-action-to-a-specific-content-type-sp-2010/) for custom action on content type.

Comment: I had tried you solution but it was creating  the custom action for that particular  site collection libraries  only.  Sub site Doc libraries are not effecting..

Comment: It is because every site has its own content type.